# Error when trying to build Freechart project in wxWidgets 3.1.1, with WX_SHARED=0

Tags: c++, build, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I wonder if anyone can help me..

I'm having a problem trying to build 'Freechart' charting widget, downloadable from here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxcode/files/Components/wxFreeChart/

Project: 'freechart-1.6.zip'

I'm using widgets 3.1.1 with a GCC compiler. I've built it with WX_SHARED=1, using the following build command:

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc WX_DIR=C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1 WX_SHARED=1 WX_UNICODE=1 WX_MONOLITHIC=1 WX_DEBUG=1 WX_VERSION=31
```

It builds and the following .a and .dll files are generated in the lib/gcc_dll folder:

- *libwxcode_msw31ud_freechart.a*
- *libwxcode_msw31ud_freechart.dll*

However, when I try to build it with SHARED=0, using:

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc WX_DIR=C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1 WX_SHARED=0 WX_UNICODE=1 WX_MONOLITHIC=1 WX_DEBUG=1 WX_VERSION=31
```

It throws the error:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxmsw31ud
```

The file exists in the widgets 3.1.1 lib directory, here:

```
C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_dll
```

There isn't an actual project file for freechart that can be opened in codeblocks, So, the widgets libwxmsw31ud.a file can't be set in the Project/Build options/Linker settings. Freechart is built in the command prompt. I'm not sure how to tell the compiler where to find this file.

As I said, the build works with SHARED=1. Any input would be much appreciated.

Paul

Comment: did you build `wxWidgets` as `static library`?

Comment: Yes, I checked the build.cfg file logs in   C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib   \gcc_dll\mswud & mswu ,  C:\wxWidgets-3.1.1\lib\gcc_lib\mswud & mswu

BUILD=debug 
MONOLITHIC=1 
SHARED=1 
UNICODE=1 

BUILD=release 
MONOLITHIC=1 
SHARED=1 
UNICODE=1 

BUILD=debug 
MONOLITHIC=0 
SHARED=0 
UNICODE=1

BUILD=release 
MONOLITHIC=0 
SHARED=0 
UNICODE=1 

The SHARED=0 (static) builds have MONOLITHIC=0 though.

Comment: I'll try doing another widgets Debug/Release build with SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1

Comment: why do you want to build as MONOLITHIC? AFAIK, only CodeBlocks itself requires it and that the reason this configuration is still exists. Otherwise it would've been dropped a long time ago.

Comment: At the time, I was new to widgets, and monolithic build was favourable, as I didn't want to go through all the individual .a files and add them into the Linker file list. I found it very tricky to get widgets to actually build and run anything at the time. The whole project I wrote uses a monolithic widgets build, so at the moment, I'll leave it as it is.

Comment: MONOLITHIC build was never favorable. As I said only CodeBlocks itself needs it. And it gave a lot of issues in the past. But I guess it is too late to change anything now... ;-)

Comment: Cool, Igor. Thanks. I get it. :) I meant favourable for me at the time. Four years ago, when I was new to this, wxWidgets monolithic build was the only mode that I could get to work. Maybe I'll go around the loop again, and build the entire thing with MONO=0.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did *not* build wxWidgets as a static library required by your build options due to the use of `WX_SHARED=0`, as you should have the outputs of this build in `gcc_lib` subdirectory and not the `gcc_dll` one. You need to either make sure that you build wxWidgets itself as static libraries (using `SHARED=0` when building it) or use `WX_SHARED=1` if you're fine with using wx DLLs.

BTW, there is absolutely *no* reason to use 4-year old wx 3.1.1, please use the much more recent 3.1.6.

Comment: Yes, I build widgets yesterday with WX_SHARED=0.  The .a files updated in gcc_lib.
I tried building freechart again. It does attempt to build now, but I get a slew of new errors, related to widgets 3.1.1. I'll get to that later.

Comment: As to there being no reason to use wx 3.1.1: The huge project that I'm using freechart with, that I started three years ago was written in it. I had so many issues with the version of widgets, where the compiler didn't function with the National Instruments hardware files. 3.1.1 was the only version that I could get to work with the hardware. I'm not going update from 3.1.1 now. I don't have the time. 3.1.1 is also consistent with our electronics engineer's version.  So, don't feel too concerned about it. – there are other factors involved. 

Paul Gasson
 6 mins ago    Delete

Comment: You won't be able to remain on 3.1.1 forever and there have been *tons* of bug fixes since then, so you risk to be running into problems that were already fixed years ago. We're very close to the new stable 3.2.0 release now and it's the best time to try upgrading, so that if you really have any problems (although I have no idea how could wx be incompatible with hardware files), they could still be reported and fixed before 3.2.0 is released.

Comment: Yep, sure, of course. Bug fixes are always ongoing.. But, the software for this machine that I built is now all complete, and has been running on a target PC for some time now. Re-building the whole thing at the moment just not viable. As I said, there is another engineer working with widgets 3.1.1, so we are both consistent in version number.  For any future projects though, upgrading to 3.2.0 would, of course be wise. (If.. I can convince the other engineers to upgrade also..)

Comment: The problem with the hardware files had something to do with the compiler that was being used. I'd have to re-visit it again to get a clearer picture of why it didn't work though. The National instruments hardware drivers that we were using were compiled at National Instruments, using the native compiler at the time with Visual Studio. I couldn't get anywhere with the earlier version of widgets. But, as soon as I tried 3.1.1, it all worked, after weeks of going round in circles.

Comment: @PaulGasson, the upgrade from 3.1.1 to 3.1.6 should be as simple as - grab the sources, compile, re-compile the application you working on. Also, just as Vadim, I would be very interested in how the library is incompatible with the hardware? Or you meant to say "incompatible with the compiler used"?

Comment: Yeah, it was a compiler issue. Looking back at my notes, I tried using MinGW-w64 compiler, but it wouldn't compile. The files included in the project was: 'NIDAQmx.h' (32 bit version). The file included in the linker settings was:   
'NIDAQmx.lib'. When I switched to GNU GCC compiler, it compiled ok. Sorry - off topic. I'll maybe start another thread about it.